# Is there an abstraction layer so I can integrate once and use either pusher, pubnub, or faye?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, faye, pusher, pubnub

I'm looking at using real time notifications in my rails 3 app but I'd like to be able to start off with [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) an maybe switch over the either [pusher](http://pusher.com/) or [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) at a later point if speed starts to become a problem.  Is there a gem or something that'll help me abstract this out?  I guess I'll also need some javascript so I can actually do the updates client side.

Comment: Why not skip faye and start with pubnub? They have free accounts with decent channel/message limits.

Comment: I might actually start with pubnub but it's more of a freedom thing.  I'd like to be able to switch easily between services if I need to.  Right now my needs are pretty meager, I just want user notifications of mentions and comment replies.

Comment: In order to achieve this you need abstraction at two layers. 1) the client e.g. JavaScript 2) the server e.g. Ruby I can see the value in this layer. However, the Pusher and PubNub APIs are so simple that swapping between them isn't difficult. That said, there are some differences in the functionality offered by the services so you won't be able to abstract those. For "user notifications of mentions and comment replies" you'll be fine, though.

Comment: @leggetter - consider posting your comment as the answer. I'll up vote it.

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you need abstraction at two layers.

1. the client e.g. JavaScript
2. the server e.g. Ruby

I can see the value in this layer. However, the Pusher and PubNub APIs are so simple that swapping between them isn't difficult. That said, there are some differences in the functionality offered by the services so you won't be able to abstract those. For "user notifications of mentions and comment replies" you'll be fine, though.

I had a look at building an abstraction at a domain specific level with [chat-js](https://github.com/leggetter/chatjs). It may be an interesting and relevant reference, although it only has a PusherAdapter right now.